# .NET 5 TLS Unexpected EOF

Tags: c#, .net-5

I recently upgraded my .net 4.8 framework project to .NET 5. I am using the MQTTNet nuget package to send MQTT messages to an AWS IOT MQTT broker. When trying to connect using .NET 5 I get the following error "Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream".

All packages and dependencies are the same.

Wireshark shows everything is fine until the client key exchange, then the error occurs.

[.NET Framework 4.8 Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCR7P.png)
[.NET 5 Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOQqT.png)

Comment: There is a diff in wireshark log to note: "Certificate Verify" is missing. What OS is running on your server side?

Comment: Can you give a try towards SAME server instance? TLS1.2 cyphers might have OS level defaults and your logs show you are trying against different IPs. The problem might be not in your code or .net versions but in host configuration difference.

Comment: Found an issue with the certificate. Turns out if Amazon IOT core does not like your certificate it will kick send an EOF prematurely